# Newtonsoft version issue with .netcore and Azure

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions

I have Solution like

1. ABC.Domain (.net standard 2.0)
2. ABC.Service (.net standard 2.0)
3. ABC.AzureFunction (.net standard 2.0) v2
4. ABC.Web (.net core 2.0)

Azure function SDK having a dependency on Newtonsoft 9.0.1 (not able to use upper version), So I used the same version on my ABC.Service project.

I using same ABC.Service reference into ABC.Web project. Now web application not allowing me to install Newtonsoft version 9.0.1.

I tried to uninstall all packages then install Newtonsoft version 9.0.1 first, but now I'm not able to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.

***Detected package downgrade: Newtonsoft.Json from 10.0.1 to 9.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.***

Any suggest??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package (version `1.0.13`) for v2 depends on `Newtonsoft.Json` version `10.0.3`.

Try changing all references to that version.